# How can I get the printer shares on a print server using Powershell?

Tags: network-share, network-printer, powershell

I'm trying to use Powershell to get the print shares from a remote print server.

I'm using:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -computerName "print-server"
```

I'm getting an "access denied" error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_Share -computerName "print-server"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I don't get why I can's see the shares, though, as if I connect through My Computer (e.g. \\print-server\) I can see all the print shares fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Ben

Comment: What's that famous quote (originally said of XML)-- something like "When you say 'I have a problem. I think I'll solve it with PowerShell!' you end up with two problems."

Comment: ugh! I love powershell!  I'd rephrase it as "When you say 'I have a problem. I think I'll solve it with PowerShell!' you end up with two problems, how to solve the original problem and how many other scripts can you replace"

Comment: What are you trying to do with the script though? You mention login script, are you trying to map a printer for a user? As mentioned you won't be able to utilize wmi to get the share names of a remote print server without admin credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can see them in Windows Explorer but get an access denied with your Powershell command because you're trying to execute a WMI query on the remote machine, for which you need valid credentials.

If you wanted to store the credentials so that you could run that command non-interactively, you could convert the password and store it as a securestring in a file, but that's just obfuscation and any intelligent snoop would be able to decode it.

```
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File secret.txt

$pass = Get-Content secret.txt | ConvertTo-Securestring
$creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist "domain\admin",$pass
```

Maybe try abandoning the WMI query route altogether.  Maybe try a good ole' COM object like so:

```
$network = New-Object -Com WScript.Network
$network.AddWindowsPrinterConnection($printerShare)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing credentials with `Get-WmiObject` as follows.

`$Credential = Get-Credential`

(You will get a prompt for credentials)

`Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName 'PRINT-SERVER' -Credential $Credential`

Comment: Or Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName 'PRINT-SERVER' -Credential (Get-Credential) for a one-liner

Comment: Trouble is, I want to run this in a login script, so don't want user to have to enter password. The bit I don't get is why I get access denied, even though I can see all the shares in Explorer...?

Comment: Are you a local admin on "print-server"?  You don't need to be an admin to see the print shares via explorer, but you need them if you are running a WMI query.